# Vuejs Template from module or by id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a template defined in my .Vue file (and its subcomponents).
My goal is to provide the customer a possibility to override this template without changing any javascript.

If an elemtent with id="search-result" exists use this one.

If not use the one defined in *.Vue file.

Can i somehow achieve this? I read about inline-Templates, but the problem is that i have a nested structure with many subcomponents.
The user would have to define the complete template instead of overriding just the one submodule he wants to override.

Do you have any hints for me?

Comment: have you tried slots?

Comment: It does not seem that this is what I'm searching for.
Slots are. I don't want to perform any complex operations or conditinal loading. I hust want to decide where my templates comes from.

Looking at the docs it's only possible by ID, "inline-template", template in *.Vue file or string-template.
My idea was to use a closure instead.

Comment: http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/333/dynamic-template/3 ?

Comment: this.$options.template = this.tpl seems to be good for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Roy J.

You can use this in your created method.

```
this.$options.template = this.tpl
```